# Efficient way of running multiple scripts simultaneously using Python

Tags: python, terminal

I have a csv file with 10,000 rows, each row contains a link, and I want to download some info of each link. As that's a consuming task I manually splitted it in 4 Python scripts, each one working on 2,500 rows. After that I open 4 terminals and run each of the scripts.

However I wonder if there's a more efficient way of doing that. Up to now I have 4 scripts .py that I manually lunch. What happens if I have to do the same but with 1,000,000 rows? Should I manually create for example 50 scripts and in each script download the info of the rows of that script?. I hope I managed to explain myself :)

Thanks!

Comment: Look into `multiprocessing.Pool()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any manual splitting – set up a `multiprocessing.Pool()` with the number of workers you want to be processing your data, and have a function do your work for each item. A simplified example:

```
import multiprocessing


# This function is run in a separate process
def do_work(line):
    return f"{line} is {len(line)} characters long. This result brought to you by {multiprocessing.current_process().name}"


def main():
    work_items = [f"{2 ** i}" for i in range(1_000)]  # You'd read these from your file
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap(do_work, work_items, chunksize=20):
            print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This has (up to) 4 processes working on your data, with, for optimization reasons, each worker getting 20 tasks to work on.

If you don't need the results to be in order, use the faster `imap_unordered`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html to make the download + processing tasks async.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Threads](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) to run multiple interpreter instances simultaneously ([https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/))

Comment: Threads don't run multiple interpreter instances.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).